# Work on docker several users same file frome different places

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, containers, continuous-deployment

I  want to know if we  have 3 developers at 3 different places. They work on same file on same container at same time.

How does Docker manage this ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "work on"?  Typical practice is to treat a container as disposable, and you wouldn't edit a file in a container directly.  Beyond that, Docker doesn't do anything special and it's handled the same way as the same action in Linux more generally.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by editing this file ?
Maybe it would be better to run multiple containers of the same image or to use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)